# Horizon in findWithingHorizon method

Tags: java, methods, java.util.scanner

What is the horizon part of the `findWithinHorizon` method?

Or in other words in the code:

```
scannerObject.findWithinHorizon(pattern, horizon);
```

What is the horizon part of the code representing? I'm guessing its something to do with how many lines of code it searches? but I'm unsure. Can anybody clarify this for me?

Comment: not sure but horizon might be one of following : `CASE_INSENSITIVE, MULTILINE, DOTALL, UNICODE_CASE, CANON_EQ, UNIX_LINES, LITERAL, UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS and COMMENTS` which are defined in Pattern class <br/> It is specified in method [findWithinHorizon with String arg](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#findWithinHorizon%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findWithinHorizon( )` attempts to find an occurrence of the specified pattern within the next count characters. If successful, it returns the matching pattern. Otherwise, it returns null. If count is zero, then all input is searched until either a match is found or the end of input is encountered.

The horizon method argument signifies how many characters have to be taken out to satisfy the pattern specified.

Comment: thankyou very much, quick question what happens when the find within horizon method with horizon 0 reaches the end of the input? does it loop back to the start of the input?

Answer (score 1):

try to have a look here! There a doc of the method.

http://www.moyosoft.com/javadocplus/demo/?fullpage=1&docclass=java.util.Scanner&docmember=findWithinHorizon